# Change direct value of array element via value of another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have task to chage direct values of array according to value of another array. For example, I have next code:

```
var elements = [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1];
var elements2 = [2, 4];
var titles = ['apple', 'beer', banana', potato', 'pear', 'pineapple'];
```

So I need to change values af **titles** with indicies 2 and 4. As you see there are values of array **elements2**.It this variant there ar 'banana' and 'pear'.
Also Ш need to say that **var elements2** is formed from **var element**. It takes all element that power than 1 (from elements). I just want to tell you that array **elements** is dynamically changed and array **elements2** changed too.
 I try to use map() function, but i can't form it correctly(. So, my unworking map():

```
var changedTitles = titles.map(function(el, i) { 
    if (i === elements2[i]) { 
        return "need to hange" + el; 
    } 
});
```

Thank you for help

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Show us your efforts that you tried so the people can help you

Comment: Change them how? What are expected results? Your problem explanation is not very clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your map function to use [`Array#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?v=control) to see if each title index exists in the elements2 array.

You also need a `return` for the `else` condition

```js
var elements2 = [2, 4];
var titles = ['apple', 'beer', 'banana', 'potato', 'pear', 'pineapple'];


var changedTitles = titles.map(function(el, i) { 
    if (elements2.indexOf(i) > -1) { 
       return "need to change " + el; 
    }else{
       return el;
    }
});

console.log(changedTitles)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! Great variant with map! Can you give little explanation what does mean `elements2.indexOf(i) > -1`?

Comment: Read the `indexOf()` documentation link I provided